# How do I create a shiny slider app to view my data over time on the map that I have created?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have used the below data frame to create a map in leaflet, using the code below. However, the output map only displays the data at each location for the last timestamp in the data. The output map is as below the code.

How do I use shiny app to display this data over the range of the "date" column that has a slider option as opposed to a map using leaflet that just shows the most recent timestamp data!

[image]

```
test_map <- leaflet(width="100%") %>%
  setView(lng=-123.2504, lat= 49.2652, zoom=15) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap")

test_map %>%
  addCircles(
    data=AQ_df,
    lng = ~Longitude,
    lat = ~Latitude,
    radius = 30,
    color = 'black',
    fillColor = ~pal(severity),
    fillOpacity = 1,
    weight=1,
    popup = paste0("<strong>ID: </strong>", AQ_df$RAMP_label, "</br>",
                   "<strong>Location: </strong>", AQ_df$RAMP_desc, "</br>",
                   "<strong>PM2.5 (ug/m3): </strong>", AQ_df$PM_RAMP, "</br>",
                   "<strong>CO (ppb): </strong>", AQ_df$CO_RAMP, "</br>",
                   "<strong>NO (ppb): </strong>", AQ_df$NO_RAMP, "</br>",
                   "<strong>NO2 (ppb): </strong>", AQ_df$NO2_RAMP, "</br>",
                   "<strong>O3 (ppb): </strong>", AQ_df$O3_RAMP, "</br>",
                   #"<strong>CO2 (ppm): </strong>", AQ_df$CO2_RAMP, "</br>",
                   #"<strong>Temperature (C): </strong>", AQ_df$T_RAMP, "</br>",
                   #"<strong>Relative Humidity (%): </strong>", AQ_df$RH_RAMP, "</br>",
                   "<strong>Date: </strong>", AQ_df$date)
  ) %>%
  addLegend(
    position = c("topright"),
    pal=pal,
    values=AQ_df$severity,
    title="<strong>PM2.5 (ug/m3)</strong>")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, you want a sliderInput that will change what the map displays?  And in what ways would it change?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)

test_map <- leaflet(width = "100%") %>%
  setView(lng = -123.2504, lat = 49.2652, zoom = 15) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap")

data <- tribble(
  ~date, ~color, ~Longitude, ~Latitude,
  "2021-09-21", "blue", -123.2464, 49.2675,
  "2021-09-20", "red", -123.2464, 49.2675,
  "2021-09-21", "black", -123.248, 49.2675
) %>%
  mutate(date = date %>% parse_date_time("%Y-%m-%d"))

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny Leaflet with Date range!"),
  sidebarPanel(
    dateRangeInput(
      "range",
      "Date range",
      start  = "2021-09-10",
      end    = "2021-09-30"
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    leafletOutput("map")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    data %>% filter(date > input$range[1] & date < input$range[2])
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    test_map %>%
      addCircles(
        data = filtered_data(),
        lng = ~Longitude,
        lat = ~Latitude,
        radius = 30,
        color = "black",
        fillOpacity = 1,
        weight = 1,
        fillColor = filtered_data()$color
      )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]